# What is the first USB URB packet transfer speed between USB device and host

Tags: linux-kernel, usb, usb-drive

When I check linux kernel USB driver code, I saw port will reset port at the beginning of init port stage. Call stack as: `hub_port_init` ->  `hub_port_reset` -> `set_port_feature`. And `set_port_feature` function will call urb to send Reset request.
But I want know what is the transfer speed of this urb message? Is it same as controller's speed? For example xhci will use 450Mbps(High Speed) to transfer?
If it is true, will 1.5Mbps(Low Speed) device still use 450Mbps speed to transfer urb packet?

Thanks!

Comment: It should do handshake at low speed to determine what capabilities are, then switch to max speed supported by both ends.

Comment: Thanks @stark for reply! But I don't found any handshake in kernel usb driver code. Would you please tell me where is it? And what detail protocol of handshake it is.

Comment: You didn't find xhci_handshake in xhci.c?